How to do maths for total gear ratio to predict 3D printed high torque high reduction planetary mesh generator?
I found a video of a guy lifting wheels and anvils using a 3D printed gearbox, so I've found a mesh generator that can rapidly produce custom gears based on that design.
I found a math walkthrough video here which I watched and took notes and tried to code, and here has formulas however the page permission is $20. The compound planets are resized so that they fit the planets on the same orbit, i.e. modulus 1.0 : 1.029 on another, which makes it very complicated to figure out.
If you can help with some math for the total ratio I will integrate them into some online tools and generators to help other engineers. Cheers!

I suggest you read up on spur gears and what a pressure angle is for them. You will find that there will always be inefficiency in gear teeth essentially sliding on one another- minimizing this can be helpful. Another point of concern is loads on the gear- if it deforms too much in the effort of converting torque
